# How to make lists reliable when designing application?

Tags: redis

I am trying to understand how should i work with Redis lists and how to make
sure it's reliable. Let's say i have a Users list with 100 users:

DAY 1:

```
RPUSH users id_1
RPUSH users id_2
RPUSH users id_3
...
...
RPUSH users id_100
```

DAY 2: Redis Crush

DAY 3: I Recover redis (using snapshots), however the snapshot was a 10 minutes before the last 5 users added to the list, so the table looks like this:

```
RPUSH users id_1
RPUSH users id_2
RPUSH users id_3
...
...
RPUSH users id_95
```

What should i do now? how will i get the rest 5 users? How do i even know that i lost data when recovering using snapshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, Redis supports AOF (append only log) persistence, so you can safely store your data

http://redis.io/topics/persistence

> the AOF persistence logs every write operation received by the server, that will be played again at server startup, reconstructing the original dataset

If you deliberately choose to use snapshots only - there's a tradeoff that you may partially lose your data and you can't do anything about it.

Redis is quite flexible in this regard - you can disable persistence at all, use snapshots only, use AOF, combine snapshots + AOF